# How can I recover my bookmarks from my mounted ubuntu OS (mounted to media directory on my running OS)?

Tags: linux

I have an old OS that I mounted to the media directory of my computer. I need to access the old bookmarks there. I remember that some bookmarks were 'single' bookmarks whereas most of them had gotten put into a group.

Previously, possibly using nano, I had been able to read the names of the single bookmarks, but not of the bookmarks in a group of some sort.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What was the old OS? What was the browser?

Comment: @DavidPostill Old OS was ubuntu - not sure which version, I think 17.04, maybe; browser was chromium. Thanks.

Comment: Copy all the bookmark files in folder ~/.config/chromium/<profile>/Bookmarks to same location on new Ubuntu and I guess all bookmarks will show up in chromium after that